# Read Kafka topic in multiple of offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume I have a topic(t) in single Kafka partition, and a single consumer in consumer-group(X) is consuming topic t. Also, assume message ordering, no partition switching.

Now I want to read the topic in multiple of offset, without me managing the consumer offset (I want auto-commit) For example following is the `topic stream with [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...] offsets and I want to set up consumer such that it reads only messages at multiple of 2, my consumer except for topic stream like 0, 2, 4 ....`

Of course, I can filter at my application level based on the offset, but I don't want to do this if there is an alternative way.

Why I want to do this imaging there is higher than expected traffic(producing more messages) but we don't want to miss execution(consumer) SLA on multiple of 2 offsets(somehow we know this are important for us), so we can skip other and just read those at a multiple of 2. Yes, splitting(different topics) is option.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to do this if there is an alternative way.

Unfortunately, there is no alternative way. Your consumer is polling batches of consecutive messages, so you'll end up almost always getting more than 1 message at a time if you are having "higher than expected traffic"

If you really wanted something like this, create a topic of two partitions, produce events with a null key, then consume from only one of the partitions